# Teradata SQL: select a literal

Tags: sql, literals, teradata

I want to use a list of arbitrary numbers as a sort of input to a select.  Option A, of course, is to create a temporary table that contains just the values (e.g., 1,2,3).

I hope that you folks know what Option >A is.

Suppose the statement is like:

```
select Fx,
XXXXXX as Foo
from MyTable
where MyTest depends on each XXXXXX
```

So if I could magically make XXXXXX a list of values (1,2,3), I'd have a resultset like:

```
    My val | Foo
    -------+---
       cat | 1
     mouse | 2
cheesecake | 3
```

Again, I could source the inputs from a table, but I prefer not to if it's not necessary.  Gurus, please chime in.

TIA.

Comment: I'm not sure what is really being asked. Can you clarify a little bit? You're not interested in joining to a numbers table, correct? Are you looking to select values BETWEEN x and y? Or are you looking to create a list and only pull back values that match (IN)? Apologizes for being dense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably find success using the ROW_NUMBER() Window Aggregate function.

Random Order

```
SELECT CALENDAR_DATE
     , ROW_NUMBER()
       OVER (ORDER BY 1)
FROM SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR
WHERE CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2010-06-01' AND DATE 
;
```

OR Order by the column

```
SELECT CALENDAR_DATE
     , ROW_NUMBER()
       OVER (ORDER BY CALENDAR_DATE)
FROM SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR
WHERE CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2010-06-01' AND DATE 
;
```

OR Partition by another column to restart the sequence

```
SELECT CALENDAR_DATE
     , YEAR_OF_CALENDAR
     , ROW_NUMBER()
       OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR_OF_CALENDAR
             ORDER BY CALENDAR_DATE)
FROM SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR
WHERE CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2009-11-01' AND DATE 
;
```

;